# WixStdBALanguageId apparently not working

Tags: wix, bundle, bootstrapper, burn

According to [documentation](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/wixstdba/wixstdba_variables.html), WixStdBALanguageId should reflect the LCID of the Standard Bootstrapper UI language.

When I call my bundle using `mybundle.exe /lang 1031`, the UI loads in German, as expected. But the log shows `Setting numeric variable 'WixStdBALanguageId' to value 1033`.

The same is true if I call `mybundle.exe WixStdBALanguageId=1031`. The GUI loads correctly in German, but the variable has the wrong value '1033'.

Why?

Comment: https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/5698

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem happened because I had a german WXL file with the wrong value of 1033 for the language tag. See the comments in the [github bug](http://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/5698)